# How are both HTTP and HTTPS versions displaying?

Tags: loop, redirect, https, http

We have a site that somehow has both http and https versions accessible. We want to force it all to https. When we try to set the WordPress and Site URLS to https the site ends up in a redirect loop.

Using Really Simple SSL doesn't really help as we still end up with a redirect loop.

Redirection plugin isn't doing anything that would cause this.

I didn't even know you could get a WordPress site to display both versions, let alone how one would go about changing this.

Googling/searching Stack exchange for this is rather difficult for obvious reasons, so I apologize if this has been answered somewhere else.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can access the SSL version of your blog without a problem, then it means you can redirect all your traffic to it. To do so, take these 2 steps:

1. Access your database using PhpMyAdmin or any other software you want. Head over to `wp_options` table, and change to values of `siteurl` and `homeurl` to SSL version of your blog (for example `https://example.com`).
2. Using any FTP software open and edit your `.htaccess` file the following way:

This will redirect all traffics to the secure version of your blog.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

#BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Remember not to remove the original rules created by WordPress (the lines below #BEGIN WordPress)

Comment: I actually used a slightly different version as yours was creating a redirect loop for some reason. ```RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]```

Answer (score 0):

Jack Johansson have answered you rightly! Alternative to this you could also install "[WordPress Force HTTPS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-https/)" plugin to do this without messing up with `.htaccess`

> Note: Don't forget to install Cloudflare plugin if in case you are using cloudflare else your site will enter into infinite redirect loop.

Comment: downvotedt as link only answers are not good answers (seriously that plugin is 5 lines of code.... you could have just included it) and it is very likely that it will cause endless redirects which is the problem the OP has with otherplugins.

Comment: There are many cases where the admin may not access the root directory or edit the `.htaccess` file. In this case plugin works best.

Comment: I am mystified, how an admin can be an admin without having access to change files? and what does it have to do with the fact that answers should include code not links?