# Adding https to wordpress website

Tags: ssl, https, cloudflare

I am using Cloudflare (service that gives free HTTPS for your website) to have https on my Wordpress website but when I change the site URL and Wordpress URL to `https://`, I get a *"redirected you too many times"* error.

I also tried to add `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` in the `wp-config.php` file and guess what? The same thing happens again. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but your help would be greatly appreciated...

I tried [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265297/how-are-both-http-and-https-versions-displaying) solution but it doesn't work but returns a 500 internal server error instead.

Comment: Did you setup AWS to send requests to HTTPS?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to WPSE. This question has been asked a lot of times before. I have an answer to this question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/265320/94498).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on `using Cloudflare` ? What exactly are you trying to do and how do you expect it to interact with your WordPress site?

Comment: @Rarst Yes, I created an account with Cloudflare to have https on my Wordpress website but when I change the settings of the website url to https:// it enters an infinite loop of redirects...

Comment: That just repeats what you stated in question. Assume others have no clue what Cloudflare is and what it has to do with https, this is important and missing context for people to grasp what is going on and do they have an idea that might make an answer.

Comment: Sorry for that but I thought people should already know what Cloudflare is... Could you please help? @Rarst

Comment: @Jack Johansson It returns a 500 internal error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are both HTTP and HTTPS versions displaying?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265297/how-are-both-http-and-https-versions-displaying)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have recently solved my issue, I went on wordpress support, found my issue and [how to fix it](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203487280-How-do-I-fix-mixed-content-issues-or-the-infinite-redirect-loop-error-after-enabling-Flexible-SSL-with-WordPress-). I installed the [SSL Insecure Content Fixer plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/) and chose in the plugin settings for SSL Detection, the setting that was recommended. Then, I went to the settings and set my Wordpress and site URL to https://. This all together fixes the infinite redirect loop.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is try to go to settings --> General and and change your Wordpress address site to a non-www URL if it has a www in it. Also, do not include a slash at the end.

One more thing, if you have any plugins activated, disable all of them and enable them one by one and see if any of them are causing an error.

Comment: Thank you but I have already solved the issue. My settings are already like you said they should be...